# Form submit button not executing code in the PHP file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to to make php execute different code based on the form input and html form does not seem to be entering php. I'm not sure what the problem with my code is

HTML:

```
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="form-holder">
    <form name="signupform" action="./php/signup.php" method="POST">
      <div class="idinput">
        <p> Enter your username:  </p>
        <input type="text" id="user_id" name="user_id" placeholder="User ID"> 
        <br>
        <div id="user_id_error"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="submitbtn">
        <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" onclick="validateForm()">
      </div>
```

validateForm() function just checks if the input is valid

Clicking the submit button does not do anything.

Comment: Try adding an `echo` above the `if` to see if PHP is even working or if it even makes it to this page.  What does the URL bar show after submit?

Comment: Is the page accessible when requesting `./php/signup.php` in your browser?

Comment: Is your `form` element closed? Have you tried removing the call to `validateForm()`?

Comment: You don't have a real submit button in your form

Answer (score 0):

You are using type button which is not used for submitting the form, inside function validateForm() you need to submit the form OR you can use type submit.

```
 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
```